# NVIDIA GTX 960M not working

Tags: drivers, nvidia, virtualbox, 15.10

I have Lenovo Y700 with Nvidia GeForce GTX 960M and Ubuntu 15.10 running in VirtualBox.

I can't get my graphical card working under Linux.

I have installed:

- `nvidia-361`
- `nvidia-opencl-icd-361`
- `nvidia-prime`
- `nvidia-settings`

In VirtualBox 3D acceleration is enabled. Yet if I run:

```
lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"
```

I get:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
```

Which I take means that Linux doesn't see my card? Also since installing the `nvidia-*` drivers Cinnamon crashes on startup (I assume this is connected with the same issue).

I tried to follow the arch-wiki and a few related answers here, but nothing seems to work (and/or seems outdated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong but I think even with 3D acceleration VirtualBox uses its own graphicscard in the VM. I think it's not possible to put your GeForce through!

Comment: Thank you for the pointer. The story is pretty complex - currently access via PCI passthrough might be possible for some kernels and cards, but the whole thing seems experimental at best... so I think I'll have to leave it as it is.